# htaccess redirect keeping url on same domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hyperlink

I want `domain.com/news.rss` to point to `/index.php?id=1&type=100`
But not a redirect, I want to keep the URL `/news.rss`

Is that possible?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/news.rss/ /index.php?id=([0-9]+)$&type=([0-9]+)$
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me, still get a 404. I changed it a little and used: RewriteRule ^/news.rss2/ /index.php?id=179$&type=100$